# Can't find plugins and modules with ESLint in WebStorm IDE

Tags: webstorm, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I've copied over an `.eslintrc` file from my old React Native project to my new fresh React Native project and I'm getting errors in the WebStorm IDE saying it can't find any of the ESLint plugins and modules.

I've configured the project to use ESLint, `.eslintrc` and to use the local ESLint rather than global.

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/Projects/foo/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --format=checkstyle --stdin --stdin-filename screens/Root.js
Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'
Referenced from: /Users/Projects/foo/.eslintrc
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'
Referenced from: /Users/Projects/foo/.eslintrc
    at ModuleResolver.resolve
```

I've checked and installed the modules using `yarn add` and I can' verify that they exist in `node_modules`, but it's still giving me the error messages.

Comment: try running `/usr/local/bin/node /Users/Projects/foo/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --format=checkstyle --stdin --stdin-filename screens/Root.js` in your system terminal - what is the result?

Comment: it just seems to hang and doesn't give a result

Comment: It waits until it receives the file content via stdin... Please try `/usr/local/bin/node /Users/Projects/foo/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --format=checkstyle screens/Root.js`